# Bash: setting for loop range via cli arg?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

Setting the for loop range to 20 like this works fine:

```
$ cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..20}; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

But how do I set the count limit using an arg from command line?

```
for i in {1.."$1"}; do
  echo "$i"
done
```

> $ ./test.sh 55
>
> {1..55}

Answer (score 0):

To extend what you already have you can use eval.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(eval echo {1.."$1"}); do
  echo "$i"
done
```